# Trouble-shooting "Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, ts-jest, jest-puppeteer

I am trying to use puppeteer for e2e testing on a react app. I'd prefer to use TypeScript, so I've tried to start with a file that begins with:

```
import puppeteer, { Browser, Page } from "puppeteer";
```

I can't seem to resolve this error, though:

```
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import puppeteer from "puppeteer";
                                                                                         ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

  at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (../node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1350:14)
```

I'm eager to learn, but not sure how to trouble-shoot this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Jest supports ES6.
Have you checked Jest docs for support -> https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules